# What is a purple file from the LS command?

Tags: ubuntu, ls, g++

I am working on a c++ project and had a failed compilation (normal kind of errors). When I ran `ls` (a bit of a habit), it showed a file with a seemingly random sequence of characters:
`'!4'$'\377\377\377\377\240''c'$'\f\276\332''U'`. LS highlighted it purple and it could not be opened in `cat` with the error `cat: '!4'$'\377\377\377\377\240''c'$'\f\276\332''U': No such device or address`. My file manager (Dolphin) could see the file, but when double clicked it reported that the file did not exist. It definitely exists as I was able to run the `mv` command to change the name (hoping it would work with the cat command). `cat` still gives the same error, just with `hello` instead of `'!4'$'\377\377\377\377\240''c'$'\f\276\332''U'`. What is this file and why did it show up? Also will it damage my filesystem to delete?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after remembering to run `ls -la`, I found out. It was a UNIX socket file from the program I was running (apparently it was from a successful run - I thought it was a failure). I'm not sure if I should delete this question or not, but it was a simple problem of being surprised at my own success.